# How do I modify a Font Awesome Icon using ::before CSS pseudo selector in a React App?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, charts, font-awesome

I have a react app in which I am using FontAwesomeIcon like :

```
< FontAwesomeIcon icon="chart-line" size="lg" className="icon trendingIcon"/>
```

It displays the chart-line icon, but I was trying to get rid of the lines that represent x and y axis on this icon, using what's in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3uvkqowo/4/

But it doesn't work. I have enabled searchPseudoElements by using:

```
window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
    searchPseudoElements: true
};
```

The ::before from css is not applied for some reason.

The css classes "icon" & "trendingIcon" are defined as:

```
.icon {
padding-right: 2%;
}

.trendingIcon {
padding-top: 1%;
padding-right: 6%;
}
```

Comment: Can u please share ur full CSS code which contains the `::before` element and also the HTML that's generated by react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to use FontAwesome's [Power Transforms](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms) (this is how you would it in [react-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome#advanced)), then you can just translate the icon down and to the left, without having to use CSS pseudo-selectors.

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jj9pwrmkxv) that shows this in action.

Your JSX would look like this:

```
 <FontAwesomeIcon
        id="edited"
        icon={faChartLine}
        size="lg"
        className="icon trending-icon"
        fixedWidth
        transform="down-4 left-4"
      />
```

And your CSS would look like this:

```
svg.icon[data-icon="chart-line"] {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: code sandbox result]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works perfectly. Do you also happen to know the consequences of using transform with FontAwesome? I mean you said if you're willing. So, I was just concerned.

Comment: Ahh, I understand your question. What I might meant by "are you willing" is "if you're not constrained by someone else's requirements that you must use CSS pseudo selectors to accomplish this" and **not** "there are a lot of dangers with using power transforms, so be very careful..." I think FontAwesone has done a great job with their library, and using transforms with svg is a great approach. I would recommend it. So, I'm glad it is working out for you. Happy coding!

Comment: Also, the title of your question assumed that the solution to your issue *must*  use `::before`. I've often found it helpful to step back from problems and ask, "Why do I think it *must* be solved with this or that approach or technology? Is there another way to solve this problem?" And that's how I stumbled on to FontAwesome's power transforms.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. Yeah I was just wondering if there's any down-sides to it. I didn't really find anything from a quick google search. So, I thought why not just ask. Happy Coding !